# How to set Safe Area Layout for new IPhone Devices in swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, safearealayoutguide

I have created a simple view.Xib file, if internet connection interrupts or disconnects for any reason my view will be displayed at the bottom.

For this I have set programmatically `NSLayoutConstraint`.

- If I use `SafeAreaLayout` it gives spaces at the bottom of every new iPhone devices like (iPhone XR, 11, Pro or Pro max).
- If I don't use `SafeAreaLayout` then view at bottom not properly displayed.

In all other devices (iPhone 7, 8 or plus) with `SafeAreaLayout` it works properly.

How can I set view properly at the bottom without space?

My Code:

```
let viewW = offlineView.fromNib()
view.addSubview(viewW)
viewW.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

viewW.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
viewW.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
viewW.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor,constant: -25),
viewW.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
])
```

```
let viewW = offlineView.fromNib()
view.addSubview(viewW)
viewW.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

viewW.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
viewW.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
viewW.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: -25),
viewW.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
])
```

Screenshots attached:

SafeArea:

[image: SafeArea]

Without SafeArea:

[image: Without SafeArea]

Constraints of Red Circle:
[image: Red Circle Constraints]

Comment: So if you don't want either of these, what kind of layout _do_ you want?

Comment: @Sweeper `without SafeArea` but it cuts view red circle. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the constraints on the red circle view?

Comment: @Sweeper I have added constraints screenshot.

Comment: Hey there! Actually, that space at the bottom is reserved for iOS-related navigation gestures and it is not advised that you include your views/layout there. That is precisely why the concept of "Safe Area" was introduced. Why does it work alright on other devices? Because the navigation stuff happens based on home-button without relying on any of screen's real estate and hence the concept of 'safe area' technically does not exist on those devices

Comment: @LokeshSN yes true I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this approach...

Constrain the "dark" view:

- Leading to **superview** Leading
- Trailing to **superview** Trailing
- Bottom to **superview** Bottom
- no Height constraint

Then, add your "circle" view as a subview of darkView, and constrain:

- Trailing to darkView Trailing: 4-pts
- Top to darkView Top: 4-pts
- Bottom to the root-view **safe-area** Bottom: 4-pts

and the label, also a subview of darkView, constrained:

- Trailing to circle Trailing: 8-pts
- CenterY to circle CenterY

Now...

Auto-layout will keep darkView's Bottom at the bottom of the screen, and darkView's Top 4-pts from Top of circle view.

Auto-layout will keep circle view's Bottom 4-pts from the Bottom of the view (when there's no soft-home-button) and 4-pts from the Bottom of the safe-area (when there *is* a soft-home-button).

Here's the results -- the yellow dashed line is the Safe-Area bounds.

on iPhone 8:

[image]

and on iPhone 11 Pro:

[image]

and how it looks in Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Thank you and let me implement and get back to you.

Comment: I have followed your mentioned steps. Thank you. Accepted and ticked.